# What do you call a person who craves danger?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who craves danger? Like how a person who believes that the pursuit of pleasure is the most important thing in life is known as a *hedonist.*

Comment: Thrillseeker?  Daredevil?

Comment: Sometimes "adrenaline junkie" if that narrowing applies.

Answer (score 1):

As Steven mentioned,

**Daredevil** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/daredevil)

> *noun* A reckless person who enjoys doing dangerous things
>   *"spectators watched in horror as the nineteen-year-old daredevil smashed into the ground"*

**Thrill seeker** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thrill-seeker)

> *noun* A person who is keen to take part in exciting activities that involve physical risk
>   *"thrill seekers are paying big bucks to swim with great white sharks"*

Answer (score 1):

**Adrenaline junkie**

> A person with a compulsive desire for excitement and adventure:

([ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/adrenaline-junkie?q=adrenaline%20junkie))

This certainly gets to the "crave" part of your request. Whether it also fits the rest will depend a little on the kinds of dangers you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

As NVZ says, *daredevil* sure is the word for that. But here are other choices for you:
**Swashbuckler**

> Someone who engages in daring adventures.

Also, I think **risk-taker** would probably replace that, because it means someone who loves taking risks.

The adjective would be **dauntless**

> To show fearlessness and determination.